# Type allowing names of fields and properties of itself and derived classes

Tags: typescript

Suppose we have a base class which should declare a method accepting a name of one of class properties or a name of properties of any derived class as a string parameter:

```
export abstract class BaseClass {
    public someField1: number = 2;

    public get someProperty1(): number {
        return 1;
    }

    public someMethod1(): void {
    }

    // TODO: What is the proper type for propertyName?
    protected method(propertyName: string): void {
        const propertyValue: any = this[propertyName];
        // ...
    }
}
```

And we have some derived class with `method()`'s test:

```
export class DerivedClass extends BaseClass {
    protected someField2: number = 2;

    protected get someProperty2(): number {
        return 1;
    }

    protected someMethod2(): void {
    }

    public test(): void {
        super.method("someField1"); // Allowed
        super.method("someProperty1"); // Allowed
        super.method("someMethod1"); // Not allowed

        super.method("someField2"); // Allowed
        super.method("someProperty2"); // Allowed
        super.method("someMethod2"); // Not allowed

        super.method(""); // Not allowed
        super.method("qwerty"); // Not allowed
    }
}
```

Here is [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20abstract%20class%20BaseClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20someField1%3A%20number%20%3D%202%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20someProperty1()%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20someMethod1()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20TODO%3A%20What%20is%20the%20proper%20type%20for%20propertyName%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20method(propertyName%3A%20string)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20propertyValue%3A%20any%20%3D%20this%5BpropertyName%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20...%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20DerivedClass%20extends%20BaseClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20someField2%3A%20number%20%3D%202%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20get%20someProperty2()%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20someMethod2()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20test()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super.method(%22someField1%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Allowed%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super.method(%22someProperty1%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Allowed%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super.method(%22someMethod1%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Not%20allowed%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super.method(%22someField2%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Allowed%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super.method(%22someProperty2%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Allowed%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super.method(%22someMethod2%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Not%20allowed%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super.method(%22%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Not%20allowed%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super.method(%22qwerty%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Not%20allowed%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A).

In the example above I've used `string` as a type of the `method()`'s parameter. But in this case, any string could be passed in and compiler is unable to verify that it's a name of an existing property.

Also, it would be nice to exclude method names (`"someMethod1"`, `"someMethod2"`) from the list of allowed values.

Which type should `propertyName` have to allow only names of fields and properties of `BaseClass` and any derived classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can almost achieve what you want to do. You can use the polymorphic `this` type to refer to the current class (so it will represent the derived class in the redrived class and the base class in the base class). We can also use `keyof` to get the keys of a type (in this case the `this` type).

There are two limitation:

- `keyof` does not return private properties of a type, this will only work with public properties
- keyof will return all properties. While it is possible to filter out the functions, this will not work inside the class (because `this` is essentially a free type parameter, it is knot fully known, since it can be this class or a derived class and we need conditional types to do the filtering which can't reasolve unless the types are fully known.

The code:

```
export abstract class BaseClass {
    public someField1: number = 2;

    public get someProperty1(): number {
        return 1;
    }

    public someMethod1(): void {
    }

    // TODO: What is the proper type for propertyName?
    protected method(propertyName: keyof this): void {
        const propertyValue: any = this[propertyName];
        // ...
    }
}

export class DerivedClass extends BaseClass {
    private someField2: number = 2;

    public get someProperty2(): number {
        return 1;
    }

    public someMethod2(): void {
    }

    public test(): void {
        super.method("someField1"); // Allowed
        super.method("someProperty1"); // Allowed
        super.method("someMethod1"); // Not allowed

        super.method("someField2"); // Allowed
        super.method("someProperty2"); // Allowed
        super.method("someMethod2"); // allowed

        super.method(""); // Not allowed
        super.method("qwerty"); // Not allowed
    }
}
```

A version that filters out functions, but only works from outside the class would use conditional types:

```
type FilterFucntion<T> = { [P in keyof T]-?: T[P] extends Function ? never : P }[keyof T]
export abstract class BaseClass {
    public someField1: number = 2;

    public get someProperty1(): number {
        return 1;
    }

    public someMethod1(): void {
    }

    public method(propertyName: FilterFucntion<this>): void {
        const propertyValue: any = this[propertyName];
        // ...
    }
}

export class DerivedClass extends BaseClass {
    public someField2: number = 2;

    public get someProperty2(): number {
        return 1;
    }

    public someMethod2(): void {
    }
}
function test(): void {
    const o = new DerivedClass()
    o.method("someField1"); // Allowed
    o.method("someProperty1"); // Allowed
    o.method("someMethod1"); // Not allowed

    o.method("someField2"); // Allowed
    o.method("someProperty2"); // Allowed
    o.method("someMethod2"); // Not allowed

    o.method(""); // Not allowed
    o.method("qwerty"); // Not allowed
}
```